# How to differentiate $\ln\cos x^{\circ}$ with respect to $x$ (not $x^{\circ}$)?

Tags: derivatives, solution-verification

**My attempt:**

$\pi=180^{\circ}$

$x^{\circ}=\frac{\pi x}{180}$

$$\frac{d}{dx}(\ln\cos x^{\circ})$$

$$=\frac{d}{dx}(\ln\cos \frac{\pi x}{180})$$

$$=-\frac{1}{\cos \frac{\pi x}{180}}\cdot(\sin\frac{\pi x}{180})\frac{\pi}{180}$$

$$=-\frac{\pi}{180}\tan x^{\circ}$$

But my book says the answer is $-\tan x^{\circ}$. Isn't my book wrong?

Comment: Maybe a misprint.  It is very unusual to do calculus with angles in degrees.

Comment: +1 for your nice attempt. I talked about this [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4191408/21813).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your book probably wants you to differentiate $\ln \cos x$ with respect to $x$, since
$$ \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d x} (\ln \cos x) = - \tan x$$
Moreover, it is a very outlandish differentiation problem which further increases the possibility that it is a typo (either in the answer or in the question itself). Otherwise, your answer is correct, and
$$ \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d x} \left(\ln \cos  \frac{\pi x}{180} \right) = - \frac{\pi}{180} \, \tan \frac{\pi x}{180}$$